# iFrame Facebook app to show it on Website

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-iframe

There is an app on Facebook which I want to show onto my Website. Is there a way which allow me to do that?

Here is a link to the Facebook app which I want embed onto my website
https://apps.facebook.com/quranic_verses/?fb_source=timeline

I have tried to iFrame the app but it is not working for me,

```
<iframe
src="https://apps.facebook.com/quranic_verses/"
width="100%"
height="310"
scrolling="no"
frameborder="0" align="center">
</iframe>
```

Thanks, appreciated!

Comment: Facebook doesn’t allow their pages to be displayed inside foreign frames. You could of course embed the app’s URL, that gets displayed inside the canvas iframe on Facebook, directly (https://quran.io/facebook/tab/, or https://quran.io/ for a larger version) – but before you do so, you should check with the owner if they want you to do so or not.

Comment: Awesome.... Copy and paste your comment down, and I will mark it as an answer. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn’t allow their pages to be displayed inside foreign frames.

You could of course embed the app’s URL, that gets displayed inside the canvas iframe on Facebook, directly (https://quran.io/facebook/tab/, or https://quran.io/ for a larger version).

But before you do so, you should check with the owner if they want you to do so or not.